# MaskedTextBox

Tags: c#, text, messagebox

Вообщем, все просто. Есть два поля для ввода текста(maskedTextBox1 и 2), нужно сделать так,  чтобы в случае того, если одно из полей не заполнено вылетал месаджбокс. Через "if (maskedTextBox1.Mask = "") MessageBox.Show("lala1");" не получается. Кстати, пытаюсь это привязать к кнопочке. Подскажите полному нулю в С# что он делает не так. Спасибо.

Comment: Что бы привязать к кнопке - самый простой путь, это добавить кнопку на форму и 2 раза на неё клацнуть, откроется процедура, которая будет выполняться при нажатии на кнопку (и в тело процедуры пишете код, который нужно выполнять)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй сделать такое условие:

```
if (maskedTextBox1.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Mask1");
}
if (maskedTextBox2.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Mask2");
}
```

Программа - http://yadi.sk/d/PMDBE7ss6yaO1

Comment: Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Советую делать так:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)) // Действие
```

В вашем случае, можно вставить пробелы и посчитает за непустую строку.